# mysqldump stuck at connecting to localhost

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-workbench

System Info:
mySQL version: Ver 8.0.27 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
windows 10 version: 20H2 19042.1586

I am trying to create a backup of a database. When I try to run the following command:

```sh
mysqldump -u root -p -v -P 3306 --quick --single-transaction sakila > sakila.sql
```

all I see in the terminal is 
`-- Connecting to localhost...`

What could I be doing wrong. I am anticipating some kind of error message but nothing happens.

I believe screenshots are against the rules, but if there is another way to visualize what's happening I can try that

Comment: Is the output file `sakila.sql` being created?  Is the size of the output file 0, or larger?  Is it continuing to grow in size?

Comment: the output file is created yes, but the size shows as 0. Does not grow in size, and when I ctrl+c out in terminal, it's still a 0 file.

Comment: I'm still getting this error...would really appreciate if someone more knowledgeable than me can help me understand what's going on

Comment: I don't know much at all about mysql,, but... I suppose you can connect to mysql for normal things, your command just hangs?  If you omit the redirection `> sakila.sql` part, do you get prompted for some input, that is not displaying when output id redirected?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out.

Instead of using Git Bash, I used PowerShell in administrator mode. The computer I'm using is heavily restricted so something must have blocked/prevented the use in Git Bash. Hope this helps someone in the future!